# Verify whether a method parameter is used in the method body

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, linter

I have an interface which looks like the following

```
interface Evaluator {
    boolean requiresP2();
    EvalResult evaluate(Param1 p1, Param2 p2, Param3 p3);
    // some more methods
}
```

This interface is implemented by several classes. The parameter `p2` of the evaluate method is used by some and not used by others. The method `requiresP2` basically returns a boolean telling whether the evaluate method uses `p2` or not.

Now, this questions may appear a little weird out of context but believe me, it makes sense in our use case. Plus, it would require a lot of time to refactor all the code to eliminate the need for the `requiresP2` method so I would appreciate if we discuss solutions other than a top-to-bottom refactoring of the codebase.

The problem is that the return value of method `requiresP2` is based on how the `evaluate` method is implemented. Therefore everyone must ensure that they update the `requiresP2` method when they change the `evaluate` method.

I am looking for ways so that this can be enforced by the compiler/unit-tests/linters rather than leaving it to the developer's memory.

**EDIT**: I am still exploring the applicability of mocking frameworks to this problem.

I thought that I could reflection in unit tests to inspect `evaluate`'s body in the unit test to check if it refers to `p2` or not and then making sure it matches with the value returned by `requiresP2` method but it seems that it is not possible to inspect method body using reflection.

I am looking for suggestions on how to do this. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.io/) to check whether the parameter is used.

To add it to your project using e.g. Apache Ivy, you would add this to `ivy.xml`:

```
<dependency org="org.ow2.asm" name="asm" rev="6.1.1" />
```

Or do the equivalent for Maven, Gradle, etc. Then you can check on the parameter by:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;

// . . .

public static boolean usesP2(Evaluator evaluator) {
    AtomicBoolean usesP2 = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    String internalName = evaluator.getClass().getName().replace('.', '/');
    String classFileResource = "/" + internalName + ".class";

    ClassVisitor visitor = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM6) {
        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name,
                String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
            if ("evaluate".equals(name)) {
                return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM6) {
                    @Override
                    public void visitVarInsn(final int insn, final int slot) {
                        if (slot == 2) usesP2.set(true);
                    }
                };
            }
            return super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        }
    };
    try (InputStream is = Evaluator.class.getResourceAsStream(classFileResource)) {
        ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(is);
        reader.accept(visitor, 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return usesP2.get();
}

public static void assertCorrectlyDocumentsP2(Evaluator evaluator) {
    boolean usesP2 = usesP2(evaluator);
    if (usesP2 && !evaluator.requiresP2()) {
        throw new AssertionError(evaluator.getClass().getName() +
                " uses P2 without documenting it");
    }
    if (!usesP2 && evaluator.requiresP2()) {
        throw new AssertionError(evaluator.getClass().getName() +
                " says it uses P2 but does not");
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
@Test
public void testFalsePositive() {
    assertCorrectlyDocumentsP2(new FalsePositive());
}

@Test
public static void testFalseNegative() {
    assertCorrectlyDocumentsP2(new FalseNegative());
}
```

(This supposes there are two bad `Evaluator`s, `FalsePositive` and `FalseNegative`, one of which documents that it uses P2 but doesn't, and the other which doesn't document that it uses P2 even though it does, respectively.)

Note: In `usesP2` we check for a variable instruction (an instruction which accesses a local variable) in slot 2 of the stack frame. The slots are numbered from 0, and the first one is `this`. P2 is in slots 2 only because `Evaluator::evaluate` is an *instance method*. If it were a **static method**, we would have to check if **slot 1** were used in order to detect if parameter P2 were used. *Caveat lector*.

Comment: Accepting this answer as this was the easiest to integrate with our setup. Thanks for the helpful answer, it solved my issue.

Comment: Interesting show case. Never heard about ASM before. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Shouldn't this check for `slot == 1` rather than `slot == 2`?

Comment: @Lakshay Read the last paragraph.

Comment: **Note** If your classes contain overloaded methods then you must match the complete method signature by using the `desc` parameter as `"evaluate".equals(name)` would not suffice

Answer (score 5):

There is another option you did not mention: a Static Code Analysis tool.

You can use the [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) + [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) combination in order to get your desired enforcement:

Use the SonarQube server in order to create a new static code analysis rule, which will be based on the interface you are using and your unique use case.

Then install SonarLint on your IDE/IDEs (Eclipse and IntelliJ are both supported), and connect it to the SonarQube server.

This way the static code analysis scan will detect improper usage of your interface and indicate this with a visual marking in the IDE, on the relevant code lines (which is actually linting your code).

Comment: This looks like a good option. I will explore the possibility of using this in our code. I will leave the question open for a while to see what other options are available.